# Converting JavaScript server to Java server

Tags: java, node.js

Well I don't know anything about JavaScript, so I ran into a small problem:

`WorldServer = require("./worldserver"),`

the previous code is JavaScript and I don't know what I should put for that in Java? Is it somekind of import or something?

what's that `require("")`;

Comment: With no context (like "what JS framework"), who knows. It probably loads a file, executes it, and returns an object. Good luck.

Comment: You need to learn Javascript.

Comment: Instead of trying to convert something, start study its functiona/purpose. The solution that you end up with in another programming language can be something completely different, not just conversion line by line.

Comment: @DaveNewton This is a JavaScript server, so my guess would be Node.js's `require` method.

Answer (score 1):

this sounds like node.js. in node.js, `require()` loads external scripts called "modules". In Java, you can use other Classes and packages by using `import`.

Comment: "Java and JavaScript are pretty similar (close enough)"  That is just wrong in so many ways.

Comment: wrong in what? syntax is almost similar, it's OOP, and the OP asked for something like an ***import*** - node has `require()`, java has `import`

Comment: They are similar in a lot of ways, in the same way that C/C++/Java/JavaScript/C# are all similar in ways.  In the context of a "how do I convert this program from JS to Java" question though, I feel like calling them "pretty similar" may mislead the OP.